# MERN - Query fetching previous dates values from DB while doing date filter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, date

MongoDB:

I have a table in mongo with timestamps attribute set. The following dates are automatically created by the DB while saving the documents.

￼[image]

Request:

Now when i am querying for the documents form the UI, the request values are like follows (date)
￼[image]

Backend Logic:

```
if (filters.date) {
    startDate = new Date(filters.date);
    startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    endDate = new Date(filters.date);
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
    endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
datePredicate = {'createdAt': {"$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate}};
```

Response:

The response received ( notice the the date is one day old )
￼[image]

In UI:

Here also it shows one day old date from the record fetched. Indeed the query fetches the objects saved on the previous day.

[image]￼

Kindly let me know why I am not getting the records for the chosen date, but one day before.

Note:
However this logic works perfectly in my localhost, just not in the prod instance.

Also when i pass the request as below, it works as expected.

[image]

￼
What am i missing? I am confused with formatting dates. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server which is not located at the same timezone you are hitting from, then you'll run into this issue, this is especially true if you are using string to communicate in between. That is also the reason why you don't see this in your localhost.

When you save the date in the database, if you are using a string, then you need to make sure it's timezone immune, which means you have to choose A) certain string format, "Z" or B) date format if it carries with the timezone. Basically you have to make sure what you stored in the database can be safely converted back to any time format in the future, ex. your browser timezone.

Simply put, "6/27/2020" is very misleading, it could mean anything. But if you are using UTC time format (ex. "Z"), then you know this date has been uniquely locked to a particular timezone. Even if you switch timezone, you'll find ways to convert in between. The base reference timezone does matter here.

Hope this helps, sorry I didn't show you any code, but this is more like a understanding question than coding problem.